# how to use toggle in button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

one for add and the other for remove

```
<div  class="to-follow col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "> 
    <button  id="follow" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="button">Follow Activities</button>
    <button id="unfollow" class=" hidden btn btn-danger btn-block">Unfollow Activities</button>
</div>
```

---

```
$(".to-follow").click(function() {
    $(this).find('button').toggle();
});
```

how to make the button follow got hide when click, and then the unfollow will show up. the function of button unfollow is same like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below.

```js
$("#follow, #unfollow").click(function () {
    $("#follow, #unfollow").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="to-follow col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <button id="follow" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="button">Follow Activities</button>
    <button id="unfollow" class=" hidden btn btn-danger btn-block hidden">Unfollow Activities</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sir but i still can see the button unfollow for a sec  when i load the page even it gone afterall, how to make the it didnt show up even the page still loading

Comment: Use `css` to hide it initially. See updated answer. @vicario

Comment: but when the button unfollow show up, it have attribute display inline block instead of block, so the button go left a little bit. how to make it display block when show up sir?

Comment: Initially add a class `hidden` to `unflow` and then use `toggleClass`. See update. @vicario

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106638/how-to-add-class-active-in-bootstrap-navbar there sir

Answer (score 1):

take 2 classes one for showing and another for hiding. Assign show class for the one you want to show by default and another will get hide class.

then your code will do rest of the work.

**check the working example below**

```js
$(".to-follow").click(function() {
    $(this).find('button').toggle();
});
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="to-follow col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "> 
    <button  id="follow" class="btn btn-default btn-block show" data-toggle="button">Follow Activities</button>
    <button id="unfollow" class=" hidden btn btn-danger btn-block hide">Unfollow Activities</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is better for you

```js
$("#follow").click(function(){
$(this).html() == "Follow Activities" ? $(this).html("Unfollow Activities") : $(this).html("Follow Activities");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="to-follow col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
  <button id="follow" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="button">Follow Activities</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can reduce it to: `$(this).html( ($(this).html() == "Follow Activities" ? "Unf" : "F") + "ollow Activities" )`

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.toggle()`-*method* changes the `style="display:none;"`-*property* of an element adding it or removing it if it exists, I think you just want to change the `hidden`-*class* you've added in your second button, then -*to do this*- you can use:

```
.toggleClass('hidden'); // instead of .toggle()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to make it so that, when you click `Follow Activities` that button is disabled and `Unfollow Activities` is enabled, and vice versa.

```js
$("#unfollow").click(function() {
  $("#unfollow").hide()
  $("#follow").show();
});  

$("#follow").click(function() {
  $("#follow").hide()
  $("#unfollow").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="to-follow col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "> 
  <button  id="follow" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="button">Follow Activities</button>
  <button id="unfollow" class=" hidden btn btn-danger btn-block">Unfollow Activities</button>
</div>
```

If you wanted, you could also make it so that the `Unfollow Activities` button is disabled by default with `$("#unfollow").hide()` before both of those functions.