# how to add class active in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello i have a navbar from bootstap and i want to add class avtive when i switch page automativly.

how to do that. i have my script but it wont work.

how to do that with jquery?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="img/logogram.png" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="people.html">people</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="inspiration.html">inspiration</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="timeline-job.html">Jobs oportunity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">hirring a chief?</a></li>
              <li><a href="register-1.html">login|signup</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

<script>
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $('.navbar ul li a').each(function () {
        var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
        // $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
        if (status) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

please help, i dont know why my query didnt work

Comment: How can you switch if there is no trigger?

Comment: i want to the the query check if the url same with the a href="[here]" it will add his own li an active class. something like that sir

Comment: Yes I know, but at least you add trigger event like click function before you add toggleClass. Oh sorry... my bad.. I see.

Comment: the trigger is when you load page sir. or switch the page

Comment: You need to change `if (status)` into `if ( -1 != status )`

Comment: and as @dewd answer use  `$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');`

Comment: all li got active class then sir

Answer (score 0):

This may work in your case, since you seem to be navigating to top level pages only:

change:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
```

to:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var loc = path.split("/").pop();
```

Also:

from:

```
var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
```

to

```
status = ($(this).attr('href') === loc);
```

The way you have this is that you will be adding the `active` class to the `a tag`. If you want to add it to the `li`, try this also:

```
if (status) {
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: var path = window.location.pathname;
    var loc = path.split("/").pop();
    $('.navbar ul li a').each(function () {
        var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
        // $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
        if (status) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    }); doesnt work sir

Comment: Try changing to the if statement to: `if (status) {   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');`

Comment: @vicario I've added another change. if still no luck could you `console.log(loc)` and `console.log($(this).attr('href'))` to see what you're getting.

Comment: didnt work sir, if i use `console.log($(this).attr('href'));` the outpit will be `undifined`. but if i use `console.log(location.href);` the output will be `file:///C:/Users/name/name/lorem/lorem/timeline-job.html`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code work:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$('.navbar ul li a').each(function () {
 var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href'));
 $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
 console.log(status);

 if ( -1 != status ) {
  console.log(status);
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
 }

});
```

Comment: still wont work sir. if i change to `if ( status )
           $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });` then all li got class active

Comment: I add `console.log` into code, let me know what you got.

Answer (score 0):

So this is fairly easy you run an each function for your `.navbar ul li a` to check if the `window.location.href` equals the navbar href.  Then you add the active class.

In bootstrap you want the active class to be added to the navbars `<li>`tag and not the `<a>` tag so in the following example I have added the active class to the parent of the `<a>` but if for some reason you don't want it to add to the li then remove the `.parent()` from the script and it will add it to the `<a>` tag.  Also you don't need to manually add the active class to the first `<li>` tag because the script will do it for you so you can remove all active classes from you navbars `<li>` tags.  All that being said your jquery script will very simply look like so:

```
$(".navbar ul li a").each(function() {   
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
});
```